# Getting ERROR o.a.j.p.h.c.CookieManager: Unable to load or invoke class: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to execute a JMeter Test Plan which have HTTP Cookie Manager.The Test Plan run successfully in standalone JMeter but fails when try to run using JMeter maven plugin.
I am getting following error on the jmx. log file.

```
ERROR o.a.j.p.h.c.CookieManager: Unable to load or invoke class: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler
        at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassTools.construct(ClassTools.java:92) ~[jorphan-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.testStarted(CookieManager.java:415) [ApacheJMeter_http-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218) [ApacheJMeter_core-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:388) [ApacheJMeter_core-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassTools.construct(ClassTools.java:86) ~[jorphan-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        ... 4 more
```

When I remove HTTP Cookie Manager sampler from Test Plan, above Error doesn't occur. Appreciate any clue to resolve this issue.

POM Configuration done like below

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        <goal>results</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jmeterVersion>4.0</jmeterVersion>
                <jmeterExtensions>
                </jmeterExtensions>
                <propertiesUser>
                </propertiesUser>
                <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                <propertiesFilesDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</propertiesFilesDirectory>
                <testFilesDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/jmeter</testFilesDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per [What's New in JMeter 3.3?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3)

> HTTP Cookie Manager Implementation Box Removed

My expectation is that your existing Test Plan has `HC3CookieHandler` in the "Implementation" drop-down which is not compatible with JMeter 4.0 which is a transitive dependency of the [jmeter-maven-plugin 2.7.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/2.7.0)

The suggested workaround is:

1. Open your Test Plan with [JMeter 3.2](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.2.zip) or earlier
2. Remove HTTP Cookie Manager from your Test Plan
3. Open your Test Plan with [JMeter 4.0](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-4.0.zip)
4. Add HTTP Cookie Manager back and configure according to your requirements.